# Arduino using N-channel MOSFET is not controlling pump as expected

Tags: microcontroller, power, mosfet, circuit-design, control

I'm trying to use an Arduino to control a humidifying system, which means it needs to control a relatively high-power pump. I thought using a MOSFET as a switch would be the easiest and best way to do this, as shown here [using this MOSFET](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/rfp30n06le-1195941.pdf).

I double-checked that I configured it correctly to this schematic I made below, but it is not performing as expected. The output pin of the Arduino is shown as a step voltage, and the DC supply represents the 12V (3A) wall adapter used to power the pump. Lastly, the ground is the ground pin on the Arduino, which is powered by my laptop, and not a DC jack.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGdKvc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wrote a simple test program for the Arduino to make sure it works. It simply drives an output pin high and low, with a couple seconds of delay between transitions. Of course I expect this to run the pump, then stop, and repeat. However, in both states the pump runs, just with slightly more power during the one period.

**What I've Done/Tried**

- I verified that the output pin of the Arduino is in fact changing between 0 and ~5V.
- I measured the voltage and amperage delivered to the pump, and it only slightly changes between states.
- I tried to measure the resistance of the motor/pump, as well as the drain-source resistance(while Vgs = 0V) but my multimeter would not give me results. (I'm assuming that these were too high for my multimeter.)

Is there a mistake with my design, my choice of N-MOSFET, or is the problem limited to a defective component or error I made in putting it together? If it is one of the former two, how can I fix this?

Comment: There is no motor in your schematic.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't show where you've put the pump in the circuit. You can just use a light bulb symbol or a box for the pump. Knowing where the pump is will greatly assist with helping you.

Comment: _"Lastly, the ground is the ground pin on the Arduino, which is powered by my laptop, and not a DC jack."_ - But it's also connected to the negative/ground part of the pump circuit, right?

Comment: _"However, in both states the pump runs, just with slightly more power during the high period."_ Are you sure the FET Drain and Source and +12V power supply are connected the right way around? Switch your meter to Diode Test and measure across the Drain and Source (with Vgs = 0V). When meter positive on the Drain and meter negative on the Source it should read an open circuit. The other way it should show a diode (~0.7V). In operation the Drain should be positive and the Source negative.

Comment: Where is the power supply? (given Vp is the pump)

Comment: @user263983 I added a resistor representing my pump

Comment: @ErikR Yes, my mistake. I edited my schematic with a resistor representing my pump

Comment: @Damien Vp is the power supply for the pump, which I forgot to add to my schematic. I added a resistor to represent the pump.

Comment: Double check that the **middle** pin of the MOSFET (and/or the tab) goes to the pump. Also, make sure there is no other path in your circuit to that node. If  you have a flyback diode (which you have not shown) it goes across the pump, not across the MOSFET (and reverse biased or you'll likely kill the MOSFET). There is nothing wrong with your schematic, it should work.

Comment: You tried to measure the resistance of the motor. What went wrong? Simply connect the motor to the 12V terminals and place an ammeter in between. the resistance is 12 volts / x ampere. However, the resistance does not matter. If the current is within the specs of your MOSFET everything should be fine.

Remember that a mosfet usually needs more than 5V to turn on properly. Even though a MOSFET is voltage controlled, you will see an (apparent) gate current. It can be very high for a short time and this is also necessary to keep the switching time short. MCU therefore often need a driver.

Comment: The datasheet for the logic-level Mosfet shows that it turns on very well when its Vgs is 5V.

Comment: While it doesn't answers your question, please note on the flyback diode as noted by @SpehroPefhany. It should be connected in parallel to the motor in reverse (i.e. cathode to the Vpp side, anode to the drain). As pump/motor are inductive load this is required to avoid burning the MOSFET once it's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the MOSFET to work, your gate voltage has to be high with respect to the source.

In the schematic, the source of the MOSFET is connected to both the ground of the Arduino and the ground of supply.

From what you say, it seems like you have connected the source to the ground of the power supply, but not to the ground of the Arduino. It has to be connected to both grounds.